# Kivy Image Widget not Moving Right

Tags: python, widget, kivy

If you look under the first GridLayout there is an Image widget.  I'm trying to get it to move to the right side of the screen.  Any help is appropriated.  Here's the code.  The id of the widget I need on the right hand side is id=image.  I can't seem to move it at all.

I'm giving more details because stackoverflow want's it.  I think the above is pretty detailed really stackoverflow, but your in charge so here is more text.

Thank you everyone.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition


Builder.load_string("""
<ClientScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        id: main_grid_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        cols: 1
        Label:
            id: name_label
            text: '<NO MENU NAME>'
            size_hint_y: None
            size: self.texture_size 
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'center'
            text_size: self.size
            padding_x: 35
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: .6, .6, .6
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        Image:
            id: image
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.5}
        ScrollView:
            id: text_scroll_view
            bar_width: 10
            size: self.size
            GridLayout:
                id: text_grid_layout
                orientation: 'vertical'
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
        ScrollView:
            size: self.size
            bar_width: 10
            size_hint_y: 0.40
            GridLayout:
                id: action_grid_layout
                # padding: [10, 10, 10, 10]
                orientation: 'vertical'
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                # row_default_height: 30
                height: self.minimum_height
""")


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ClientScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        from kivy.core.window import Window

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.transition = NoTransition()

        global CLIENT_SCREEN

        LOGIN_SCREEN = LoginScreen(name='login')
        CLIENT_SCREEN = ClientScreen(name='client')

        sm.add_widget(LOGIN_SCREEN)
        sm.add_widget(CLIENT_SCREEN)

        sm.current = 'client'

        Window.size = (300, 120)
        self.title = 'xNemesis Client V0'

        return sm


MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the kv file, do the following. Please refer to the example below for details.

1. Replace `GridLayout:` with `BoxLayout:` because `GridLayout` with `cols: 1` has the similar presentation as `BoxLayout` with `orientation: 'vertical'`.
2. Remove `cols: 1`
3. At `Image:`, add `size_hint_x: 0.4`
4. Replace `pos_hint: {'right': 0.5}` with `pos_hint: {'right': 1}`

## Note

*GridLayout does not has an attribute called orientation.*

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, NoTransition


Builder.load_string("""
<ClientScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: main_grid_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            id: name_label
            text: '<NO MENU NAME>'
            size_hint_y: None
            size: self.texture_size 
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'center'
            text_size: self.size
            padding_x: 35
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgb: .6, .6, .6
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        Image:
            id: image
            source: 'raspberrypi.png'
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            pos_hint: {'right': 1}
        ScrollView:
            id: text_scroll_view
            bar_width: 10
            size: self.size
            GridLayout:
                id: text_grid_layout
                orientation: 'vertical'
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
        ScrollView:
            size: self.size
            bar_width: 10
            size_hint_y: 0.40
            GridLayout:
                id: action_grid_layout
                # padding: [10, 10, 10, 10]
                orientation: 'vertical'
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                # row_default_height: 30
                height: self.minimum_height
""")


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ClientScreen(Screen):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        from kivy.core.window import Window

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.transition = NoTransition()

        global CLIENT_SCREEN

        LOGIN_SCREEN = LoginScreen(name='login')
        CLIENT_SCREEN = ClientScreen(name='client')

        sm.add_widget(LOGIN_SCREEN)
        sm.add_widget(CLIENT_SCREEN)

        sm.current = 'client'

        Window.size = (300, 120)
        self.title = 'xNemesis Client V0'

        return sm


MyApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]